# python3.7で、Numpyのインポートができません

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

Anacondaをダウンロードし、パッケージ内のPython3.7でNumpyを使いたいのですが、「import numpy as np」と打つと「ModuleNotFindError:No Module Named 'numpy'」というエラーが返ってきます。
解決策として以下の方法を試してみましたが、状況は変わりませんでした。
Anacondaの前にPipからPython3.6をインストールしていたので、古いほうのPythonはアンインストール。
Python本体とNumpyが同じ格納場所にあると上手く行かないと聞いたため、anacondaのファイル内からPython関係のファイルをすべて別ドライブに移動。
それでも上手く行かなかったので、Python関係のファイルとNumpy関係のファイルを、同一ドライブ内の別の場所に格納。

あと、PythonとNumpyのバージョンがあっていないとエラーが出るという情報もありましたが、今回は両者とも同じanacondaのパッケージ内にあったものなので、その可能性はないと思っています。
コンピューター自体にあまり詳しくないので、的外れなことを書いているかもしれませんが、ほかに解決策があれば、ご指導お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

ぱっと見た限り、Anaconda のディレクトリ構造を壊したために NumPy が見つからなくなっているように思えます。一度 Python 関係のものを全てアンインストールし、Anaconda のインストールからやり直してください。

具体的には以下のことが気になります。

1. pip は Python のパッケージをインストールするツールであり、Python 本体をインストールするものではありません。
2. 元々何かしらの方法で Python がインストールされていた環境に Anaconda をインストールなさったようなので、その 2 つの環境が混ざってしまっている可能性がありそうです。
3. 「Python本体とNumpyが同じ格納場所にあると上手く行かないと聞いた」とのことですが、よく分かりません。Anaconda がよしなに管理してくれていたファイルたちを手動で移動するとファイルパスが変わるので管理できなくなります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。おっしゃる通りに、パソコン内のpython関係ファイルと、アナコンダをコントロールパネルからアンインストールしようとしたのですが、Python3.6.5とPython3.7.0というソフトが、アンインストールされずに残ってしまいました。何度か試してみましたが、No Python3.6 installation was detected というメッセージが出た後、一向にアンインストールが進みません。

Comment: ちなみにAnacondaのソフトは　Anaconda.incが発行元になっているのですが、アンインストールできないファイルは、Python Software Foundationが発行元になっています。anacondaインストール前に入っていたパイソンが残ってしまっているのだと思うのですが、このファイルはコントロールパネルではなくアンインストーラを使わなけれはならないということでしょうか？おそらく中途半端にアンインストールしたせいでアンインストーラがないのですが、その場合はアンインストーラをインストールしなおす必要があるのでしょうか？

Comment: @user32020 うーん、ちょっとこれだけだと状況を把握しにくいです。全てアンインストールするのが良いと思うのですが、いま PATH にいる Python たちがどういったものなのか把握できません。詳細情報も含めて新しく質問を作って頂けませんか？　その際、行った手段を逐一箇条書きで詳細に書いていただけると回答しやすいです。